# code to solve the "Theater Row" brain teaser

Tags: c++, simulation, probability, approximation

I was reading a book called "Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability", which is filled with lots of probability-related brain teasers. I wasn't able to solve one of the problems there, and wasn't able to understand the solution, either. So, I was writing a code to get a better feeling. Here is the original problem.

> *The Theater Row:
>   Eight elegible bachelors and seven beautiful models happen randomly to have purchased single seats in the same 15-seat row of a theater. On the average, how many pairs of adjacent seats are ticketed for marriageable couples?*

And here is my code, getting an average number of adjacent pairs out of 100 random sampling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

//  computes the probability for the "theater row" problem 
//  in the book fifty challenging probabilty problems.

vector<int> reduce(vector<int>& seats);    //  This function reduces a sequence to a form 
                                           //  in which there is no adjacent 0's or 1's.
                                           //  *example: reduce(111001)=101*

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int total=15;
    int Num=100;
    int count0=0;   //  number of women
    int count1=0;   //  number of men
    vector<int> seats; //   vector representing a seat assignment, 
                       //   seats.size()=total
    vector<int> vpair; //   vector that has number of adjacent pairs 
                       //   as its element, size.vpair()=Num

    for (int i=0; i<Num; ++i) {
        count0=count1=0;        
        while ((count1-count0)!=1) {
                    count0=count1=0;
            seats.clear();
            for (int j=0; j<total; ++j) {
                int r=rand()%2;
                if (r==0)
                    ++count0;
                else
                    ++count1;
                seats.push_back(r);
            }
        }

        for (int k=0;k<seats.size();++k)
            cout<<seats[k];

        reduce(seats);

        for (int k=0;k<seats.size();++k)
            cout<<" "<<seats[k];

        vpair.push_back(seats.size()-1);   // seats.size()-1 is the number 
                                               // of adj pairs.
        cout<<endl;
    }

    double avg=static_cast<double>(accumulate(vpair.begin(),vpair.end(),0))/vpair.size();

    cout<<"average pairs: "<<avg<<endl;


    return 0;
}

vector<int> reduce(vector<int>& seats)  
{
    vector<int>::iterator iter = seats.begin();
    while (iter!=seats.end()) {
        if (iter+1==seats.end())
            ++iter;
        else if (*iter==*(iter+1))
            iter=seats.erase(iter);
        else
            ++iter;
    }
    return seats;
}
```

The code generates random series of 0's (representing women) and 1's (men). It then "reduces" the random sequence so that there are no repeating 0's or 1's. For example, if the code generates a random sequence of 011100110010011 (which has 7 adjacent pairs), the sequence is reduced to 01010101. In the reduced format, to figure out the number of adjacent pairs, you just need to get the "size-1".

Here are my questions.

1. The answer to the question (according to the book) is 7.47, while I get an average of about 7 or so from the code. Does anybody see where the discrepancy originates?
2. My code seems quite inefficient sometimes. Is it due to the way I generate a random sequence? (As you can see, to generate a random sequence of 8 men and 7 women, I keep asking for a random sequence of size 15 until it happens to have 8 men(or "1") and 7 women(or "0"). Is there a better way to produce a random sequence when there is a constraint like this?

I am not so proficient when it comes to programming. I'd appreciate any comments. Thank you for you help!!

Comment: What state is this theater in?  Could be 100% every time. (Ignore. Just a moment of levity!)

Comment: I found a bug and fixed it. Answer from the simulation seems right.

Comment: How do you get the answer 7 from the sequence 011100110010011?  Is this theatre in a country that allows polygamy, but not same-sex marriage?  To put it less flippantly, the question doesn't seem to make it clear whether two pairs can include the same individual.

Comment: The question cannot be answered given the available information. You also need to know the marriage laws of the jurisdiction in question. Can people of the same sex marry? Different race? Different religion? If race or religion is a restriction on marriage in the question's jurisdiction, what are the races and religions of the people in question?

Comment: Was the point of the exercise to approximate it through simulation?  That's not a very elegant way of addressing a problem that has a unique/precise mathematical answer...

Comment: FWIW: here's a document from the Stanford Educational Studies Program that discusses this problem (along with several others from the book):  http://www.stanfordesp.org/media/uploaded/11_04/M1232_SPLASH_Puzzling_Problems_in_Probability.pdf

Comment: /Michael, thanks for the link.

Comment: /HostileFork, you are absolutely right in this particular case. But there are several problems from the book in which running small codes give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem is hilarious.

There are 1307674368000 possible combinations.

There is 203212800 combinations where 1 couple gets together.

But there are 3048192000 combinations where 2 couples get together.

Think the key to this problem would be doing a smaller scale problem first and use that info to create your answer. This is just a expected value problem.

Edit: Instead of running simulations, you could just get the exact answer using expected value, will have to think harder, but you also will be exact. I'll take a little bit to see if I can come up with the exact answer and post it.

Important Edit(Read):

Does your code account for if you if you get more than 8 0's or 8 1's. Sense you only can at most have 8 men and 7 women, then it should automatically feel the rest with the left over symbols.